# vba html form filling (ie or chrome) - problem with onkeypress

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, forms

I’ve tried to make macro for this site (https://webcik.posta.hu/) to autofill this form (https://webcik.posta.hu/FeladoCimzett.aspx). I manage to navigate to the form, and fill some of the fields, here is my macro:

```
Sub postaautofill()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://webcik.posta.hu/Bejelentkezes.aspx"

    While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnBejLak").Click

    While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

    Set doc = IE.document

   ’consignor data

    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlArufiz").Value = "Szla"

    Set objButton = IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlArufiz")
    objButton.Focus
    objButton.Click

    While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

    IE.document.getelementbyid("ContentPlaceHolder1_MaskedEditExtender1_ClientState").Value = "bank account nr."
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFnev").Value = "name"
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFEmail").Value = "mail"
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFTel1").Value = "00"
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFTel2").Value = "0000000"
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFIRSZ").Value = "0000"
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFTelep").Value = "Town”
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFKozterNev").Value = "name of street"
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFKozterJelleg").Value = "utca"
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFHsz").Value = "0"

’consignee data
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCNev").Value = Sheets("Partner").Range("A2").Value
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCIRSZ").Value = Sheets("Partner").Range("B2").Value
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCTelep").Value = Sheets("Partner").Range("C2").Value
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCKozterNev").Value = Sheets("Partner").Range("D2").Value
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCKozterJelleg").Value = Sheets("Partner").Range("E2").Value
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCHsz").Value = Sheets("Partner").Range("F2").Value
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCEmail").Value = Sheets("Partner").Range("H2").Value
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtMegjegyzes").Value = Sheets("Partner").Range("G2").Value
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCTel1").Value = Sheets("Partner").Range("I2").Value
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCTel2").Value = Sheets("Partner").Range("J2").Value
    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUF1").Value = Sheets("Partner").Range("K2").Value

    While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

    IE.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnTovabb").Click

End Sub
```

I’ve manage to choose the second option, but bank account field won’t appear, and couldn’t fill it

```
<div class="input unit two-of-three4">
                                        <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlArufiz" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlArufiz\',\'\')', 0)" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlArufiz">
        <option selected="selected" value="Cim">Címre</option>
        <option value="Szla">Számlaszámra</option>


bank account field html code:
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_SzlaDIV">
                                    <div class="label unit one-of-three">
                                        <label for="bankszamlaszam">
                                            Bankszámlaszám:</label></div>
                                    <div class="input unit two-of-three4">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$MaskedEditExtender1_ClientState" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_MaskedEditExtender1_ClientState">
                                        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSzla" type="text" value="________-________-________" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSzla\',\'\')', 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSzla" class="error">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="label unit three-of-three">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

I also have problem filling the fields, which have this javascript code:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtFIRSZ" type="text" maxlength="4" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtFIRSZ\',\'\')', 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFIRSZ" class="alert">
```

I tried many possible solutions FireEvent, and change to chrome (selenium), however the result unfortunatelly is the same. I’m not really experienced with javascript which would be the solution I guess.

So I have stuck at this stage, and I really appreciate every help, and solution to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance!